# is there any way to automatically run a test suite from within Selenium IDE upon opening firefox?

Tags: testing, browser, automation, selenium, selenium-ide

I would like to create a script or a batch file on windows that automatically opens Selenium IDE (plugin) and opens and runs a test file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend Selenium RC for running automated Selenium tests. You can easily export tests from IDE into several languages supported by Selenium RC and then use an appropriate test framework. It is also possible to run IDE tests written in HTML through Selenium RC using the htmlSuite command line parameter.

- [Selenium RC documenation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html)
- [How to run Selenium IDE tests within Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#html-suite)

Answer (score 1):

Try it!

Save the below commands in a batch file and schedule when you want. You can place it in start up to start your scripts when you start your system.
C:
CD \selenium-remote-control-1.0.1\selenium-server-1.0.1
java -jar selenium-server.jar -port 4444
java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*iehta" "http://www.testsite.com/" "C:\testsuite.html" "C:\Results.html"
Pause